# Proof strategy for $(=>)$: If $g \circ f = id_A$, then f onto $\iff$ g 1-1. [Chartrand 3Ed P239 9.72]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, intuition, visualization

> For nonempty sets A and B and functions f : A → B and g : B → A, suppose that $g \circ f =$  the identity function on A. $(♦)$
>
> (d) $(=>)$ Assume that $f$ is onto. This means there exist $a_1, a_2\in A$ such that $f(a_1)=b_1$ and $f(a_2)=b_2$, , where $b_i\in B$
>
> Suppose that $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$.  Substitute $b_i$ with the above equations for $f(a_i)$: $ g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2))$. By virtue of (♦), we have $a_1=a_2$.

What's the proof strategy? I'm not asking about the proofs, but they both look guileful and wily. For example, how would one determine when to apply $f$ or $g$? I realise that the proof leverages $(♦)$.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: It's "What are the proof strategies for (d) and (e)?" Is there something to be improved in my OP?

Comment: Ok... I can say no better than what you have written.... hope some one helps you

Comment: I think you got the right idea of the proof but the writing of $d)$ is bad: we don't know what are $b_1$ and $b_2$ are in the first sentence. The redaction of $d)$ should start by: Let assume that $f$ is onto. We consider $b_1$ and $b_2$ in $B$ such that $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$...

A mathematical proof is like a weel-written story: you should always introduce the characters before the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the proof strategy is just to write down your conclusion and your premise, and at every step just write down the first thing you can do with the tools you are given.

Always start by writing down the premise:

> Suppose that $g \circ f = id$ and $f$ is onto.

We would like to show that $g$ is one-to-one, which means $g(a) = g(b) \implies a = b$.  To show this, start with the premise:

> Suppose that $b_1,b_2 \in B$ and $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$.

Now what?  Well, there aren't very many possible options at this point as we only have a few symbols.  We have some $b_1,b_2$ - what can we do with them?  We have to use the premise somewhere, which is that $f$ is onto.    Even if we don't see immediately how it's useful, there's only one thing we can say:

> Since $f$ is onto, there exists $a_1,a_2 \in A$ with $f(a_1) = b_1$, $f(a_2) = b_2$.

What now?  There's only one thing we know about $b_1,b_2$, and one thing we know about $a_1,a_2$, so put them together and rewrite what we have.

> Then $g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2))$.

But then we're already finished.

> But $g\circ f = id$, so $a_1 = g(f(a_1)$ and $a_2 = g(f(a_2)$, and so $a_1 = a_2$.

Tim Gowers has written some nice [blog](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/how-to-work-out-proofs-in-analysis-i/) posts about this kind of proof.  You don't have to be clever - just write down the premise and then keep writing down something you can do with the symbols you currently have according to what you know at that point.  In my experience students mainly have trouble getting the logical form of the argument right rather than coming up with the individual steps.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. Would you please answer for (e) as well in your answer, and not as a comment? I should've asked about (e) first because its proof is harder than that for (d).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real answer but more an alternative proof. If it is useless in this context then please let me know. In that case I will delete the answer.

If $g\circ f=id$ then $g$ is surjective since $g\left(f\left(a\right)\right)=a$
for each $a\in A$. So if $g$ is injective as well then it is bijective
(i.e. isomorphic in the category of sets) and, as its inverse, $f$
is bijective too.

If $g\circ f=id$ then $f$ is injective since $f\left(a\right)=f\left(b\right)$
leads to $a=g\left(f\left(a\right)\right)=g\left(f\left(b\right)\right)=b$.
So if $f$ is surjective as well then it is bijective (i.e. isomorphic
in the category of sets) and, as its inverse, $g$ is bijective too.